# angular rxjs observables/subjects subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I using angular 15.
I learned that when using observable etc, it is critical to handle potential memory leaks.
I understood that using `async pipes` is best practice because angular then takes care of that.
There are a lot scenarios where one still might want to use observable / subject etc differently.
In my example I need to convert an existing (external) function call *refreshData()* to an event stream because I want to handle it differently.

so I have following code:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subject$ = new Subject();

    this.experimentTemplates$ = this.subject$
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => console.log('a finalized?')),
        throttleTime(10000), // reduce server load
        switchMap(() =>   // map to data
          this.service
            .getData()
            .pipe(finalize(() => console.log('b finalized?')))
        )
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => console.log('c finalized?')));
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.subject$.next(); // trigger initial load
  }

  // externally called function that used to directly load data
  public refreshData(): void {
    this.subject$.next();
  }
```

my view is bound like this:

```
[experimentTemplates]="experimentTemplates$ | async"
```

I get following logs:

1. 'b finalized?' -- on every actual (throttled) refresh via function call `refreshData()`
   then after destroying the component:
2. 'c finalized?'
3. 'a finalized?'

I think I understand why 'b finalized?' occurs.
Then I'd say that 'c finalized?' is because angular unsubscribes `experimentTemplates$` on destroy (because of the async pipe)
'a finalized?' is probably no different to 'c finalized?', but
what is about `subject$`? Do I even need to bother about this?

Comment: I have assumed that when you use the async pipe on a variable on the left hand side (LHS) of an equals sign that RxJS automatically subscribes to the Observable on the right hand side (RHS) of the equals, which is the Subject. I would further assume that when the async pipe unsubscribes from the LHS it also unsubscribes from the RHS.

Comment: I put together a stackblitz here to try it out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mfvnhg

Comment: @DeborahK not sure why you used BehaviorSubject but your example matches my findings.

Comment: I used `BehaviorSubject` to have it emit the first time instead of using `ngAfterViewInit` because the `ngAfterViewInit` was generating a "Expression has changed after it was checked" error in my implementation.

Comment: i dont get that though